# How to insert cronjobs using bash without evaluating command?

Tags: bash, cron, escaping

I'm using a bash oneliner to create a cronjob that saves files to a path that depends on the current time, hence I'm using `date`. However, the `date` expression is evaluated when I insert the cronjob, while I want the `date` expression to be evaluated when cron runs the job.

My command is like this:

```
bash -c "(crontab -r; echo \"* * * * * /usr/bin/wget -o /backups/\$(date +\%F_\%R).sql 127.0.0.1:8000/api/export/full\") | crontab -"
```

How can I alter this command to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the argument to `echo` in single quotes rather than double quotes, so there won't be any evaluation of `$(...)` inside it.

There's also no need to include `crontab -r` in the command that's piped to `crontab -`.

```
bash -c "crontab -r; echo '* * * * * /usr/bin/wget -o /backups/\$(date +\%F_\%R).sql 127.0.0.1:8000/api/export/full' | crontab -"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes instead of double quotes. Bash does not do variable expansion in strings with  single quotes. You can either use single quotes for the inner string (argument to echo) or for the outer one (and use unescaped double quotes for the inner one then)

Comment: You can't escape single quotes inside single quotes.

Comment: @Garmar That's surprisingly true. Edited.

Comment: @JohannesH. `echo $'It\'s possible with C-style strings.'`